# How to clone the current document to an IFrame with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Task:

When my homepage loads, I want to load the page normally.  After all the scripts have run, I want to use Jquery to inject an IFrame into the body, and use it to clone the current page.  ( Why? So I can have a part of the page that doesn't reload between pages in my site. )

I can inject the iframe and clone the page successfully, using the src attribute, however, this causes everything on the page to download twice (once when the page loads the first time, and again when the script injects the iframe).

So, I would like to use JQuery to clone the current page ( head and body ), and either append it into the Iframe, or use the new html5 srcdoc attribute.

Presently, I am having no joy with either route.  Let me outline the two methods here:

#### Clone and Append

```
    // Get the width & height of current window
  wwidth = $(window).width();
  wheight = $(window).height();

  // inject the iframe 
  $("body")
   .append(
   '<iframe seamless ' + 
   ' class="hidden" id="iframe" border="0" frameborder="0" width="' 
   + wwidth + '" height="' + wheight + '"></iframe>' 
   + '<div id="temp"></div>'
   );

                // Attempt to replace iframe contents with current page contents
                $('iframe').contents().replace( $("html").clone().not("iframe") );
```

That injects the iframe but doesn't replace the content.

#### Use SRCDOC

```
// Same as above bu this part
// Attempt to set iframe contents with srcdoc
$('iframe').attr("srcdoc" , $('html').clone() );
```

Produces the result srcdoc="[object][Object]"

P.S. I tried to add the srcdoc tag, but I can't.  Someone with higher points please?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from SRCDOC(I didn't know yet).

I'm afraid clone() will not be an option. Regarding to the DOM-specification it's not allowed to move nodes between documents(and at least in MSIE it isn't possible). There is a DOM-method to import nodes, but as far as I know this method(`DOMDocument->importNode()`) isn't supported by any browser.

Furthermore: cloning wouldn't prevent from "double-downloading" in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can tell, the `srcdoc` attribute is not supported by IE 9, FF 5, Chrome 12, or Safari 5 (on Win 7).

Even simple examples like this don't work (yet):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe seamless
                sandbox="allow-same-origin"
                srcdoc="<p>My fav search engine is <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>.">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```